# Change leaflet heatmap options in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet, heatmap, r-leaflet

I am using **leaflet-heat.js** plugin for leaflet.
The only way that I could make it work, was through the rCharts library.
[R shiny leaflet javascript addons - heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32378118/r-shiny-leaflet-javascript-addons-heatmap)

The heatmap displays correctly, but I cannot change the heatmap options.
In addition, if I uncomment the reactive part of the code, the app crashes.

It seems that the only way to modify the heatmap layer opacity is through CSS, but I cannot figure out how to implement it here.
[control the opacity of heatmap using leaflet heatmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25974054/control-the-opacity-of-heatmap-using-leaflet-heatmap)

Here is the part of the code that works, with the offending lines commented out.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rCharts)

# Define UI for app

header1 <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard"
)

sidebar1 <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    fileInput("file0", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
    sliderInput("opacity", "Opacity:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 0.5, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("radius", "Radius:",
                min = 0, max = 50,
                value = 25),
    sliderInput("blur", "Blur:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 0.75, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("maxvalue", "MaxValue:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 1, step = 0.05)
  ) #sidebarMenu
) #dashboardSidebar

body1 <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = "Box Title 1", width = 11, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
      chartOutput("baseMap", "leaflet"),
      tags$style('.leaflet {width: 600px; height: 400px;}'),
      tags$head(tags$script(src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js")),
      uiOutput('heatMap')
    ) #box
  ) #fluidRow
) #dashboardBody

ui <- dashboardPage(header1, sidebar1, body1)

# Define data
dat <- data.frame(latitude = c(14.61),
                  longitude = c(-90.54),
                  intensity = c(100))

# Define SERVER logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  opacityoption <- reactive({
    paste("minOpacity = ",as.character(input$opacity))
  })

  radiusoption <- reactive({
    paste("radius = ",as.character(input$radius))
  })

  bluroption <- reactive({
    paste("blur = ",as.character(input$blur))
  })

  maxoption <- reactive({
    paste("max = ",as.character(input$maxvalue))
  })

  output$baseMap <- renderMap({
    baseMap <- Leaflet$new() 
    baseMap$setView(c(14.61,-90.54) ,12) 
    baseMap$tileLayer(provider="Esri.WorldTopoMap")
    baseMap
  })

  output$heatMap <- renderUI({

    j <- paste0("[",dat[,"latitude"], ",", dat[,"longitude"], ",", dat[,"intensity"], "]", collapse=",")
    j <- paste0("[",j,"]")
    j

    tags$body(tags$script(HTML(sprintf("
                                       var addressPoints = %s
                                       var heat = L.heatLayer(addressPoints).addTo(map)"
                                       , j)
    )))

    # THESE LINES DO NOT WORK - THE OBSERVE BLOCK CRASHES
    # tags$body(tags$script(HTML(sprintf("heat.setOptions(minOpacity = 0.5)"
    # )))) #tags$body

    # tags$body(tags$script(HTML(sprintf("heat.setOptions(radius = 50)"
    # )))) #tags$body

    # observe({
    #   tags$body(tags$script(HTML(sprintf(paste("heat.setOptions(",opacityoption,", ",radiusoption,", ",bluroption,", ",maxoption,")")
    #   )))) #tags$body
    # }) #observe

  }) #renderUI

} #server


# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Your help on this will be greatly appreciated!  :)

Comment: if you are interested in heatmap, have you seen this: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/leaflet.extras/versions/0.2/topics/addHeatmap

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!  I tried it out with leaflet.extras library, but the heatmap part crashes.  Here is my code.  Some lines are commented, because they crash the app.

Comment: Please see the question edit ...

Comment: The app now works with leaflet in shiny.  But whenever I try to do this inside the server block, it crashes.     # THESE BLOCK IS COMMENTED OUT BECAUSE IT CRASHES
  # addHeatmap("MapPlot1", lng = -90.54, lat = 14.61, intensity = 1,
  #            minOpacity = 0.05, max = 1,
  #            radius = 25, blur = 15,
  #            data = leaflet::getMapData(map))

Comment: I also need to know how to update the heatmap options ...     observeEvent(input$opacity, {
    
    # HOW DO I UPDATE THE HEATMAP OPTIONS HERE INSIDE OBSERVE EVENT?
    
  }) #observeEvent

Comment: Library leaflet.extras seems to add functionality to leaflet through third party plugins.  This means that plugins like leaflet-heat.js can be used inside Shiny instead of what I am doing here with rCharts.  Can you give me just one example of the syntax needed to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for something like this? Here is an example with `addHeatmap`. Just move your `sliderInput` and you will see the map will change accordingly. It seems to be not working for the `maxvalue`, but change the numbers in your `sliderInput` and it will work. You may want to look also in `leafletProxy`.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(leaflet)
library(leaflet.extras)

# Define UI for app

header1 <- dashboardHeader(
  title = "My Dashboard"
)

sidebar1 <- dashboardSidebar(
  sidebarMenu(
    fileInput("file0", "Choose CSV File",
              multiple = TRUE,
              accept = c("text/csv",
                         "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",".csv")),
    sliderInput("opacity", "Opacity:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 0.5, step = 0.05),
    sliderInput("radius", "Radius:",
                min = 0, max = 50,
                value = 25),
    sliderInput("blur", "Blur:",
                min = 0, max = 30,
                value = 0.75, step = 2),
    sliderInput("maxvalue", "MaxValue:",
                min = 0, max = 1,
                value = 1, step = 0.05)
  ) #sidebarMenu
) #dashboardSidebar

body1 <- dashboardBody(
  fluidRow(
    box(
      title = "Box Title 1", width = 11, solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",
      leafletOutput("baseMap"),
      tags$style('.leaflet {width: 600px; height: 400px;}'),
      tags$head(tags$script(src="http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.heat/dist/leaflet-heat.js"))
    ) #box
  ) #fluidRow
) #dashboardBody

ui <- dashboardPage(header1, sidebar1, body1)

# Define data
dat <- data.frame(latitude = c(14.61, 15),
                  longitude = c(-90.54, -90.65),
                  intensity = c(100, 125))

# Define SERVER logic
server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$baseMap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(data = dat) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Stamen.TonerLite,
                                   options = providerTileOptions(noWrap = TRUE)) %>% setView(-90.54, 14.61, zoom = 12) %>%
      addHeatmap(lng = ~longitude, lat = ~latitude, intensity = ~as.numeric(intensity), minOpacity= ~input$opacity, blur = ~input$blur, max = ~input$maxvalue, radius = ~input$radius)
  })


} #server


# Run app
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Awesome!  This gets in the right direction!  However, blur and maxvalue have a problem, because they seem to jump from 0 to infinity when their values are greater than zero.  Is there no solution to opacity?  I would love to make it work like this ...  http://heatmap.joyofdata.de/

Comment: see update, you can use minOpacity; Have you tried with a bigger dataset?

Comment: Hi MLavoie!  My lower and upper bounds for the parameters were wrong.  Your example now works!  However, the minOpacity parameter behaves differently than initially expected - it seems to do the opposite of the maxvalue parameter.  Is there a way to control the overall opacity of the heatmap layer?

Comment: Try opacity in the tile options argument

Comment: minOpacity parameter works in a weird way when you have only a few points.  After adding more points, minOpacity works as expected.